# Is it possible in from clause use case when statement

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to do next query:

```
select * from (case when :p1 = '1' then t1 when :p1=2 then t2);
```

But it's not working. I assume that case when statement isn't allowed in from clause? Is there any other any way to resolve this.
Thanks

Comment: Assume that you are trying to use a table name which should be conditional, correct? Well PL/SQL is an option or you can create a function as well.

Comment: @user75ponic True, tablename is optional. When parameter is equal to 1 then collecting data from t1, when parameter is equal to 2 then collecting data from t2. Can help me with this?

Comment: Use a PL/SQL block or create a function to verify parameter is 1 or 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't do that. The objects and identifiers have to be fixed when the query is parsed, so you can't bind those.

You could use a union with a check for the variable in each branch:

```
select * from t1
where :p1 = 1
union all 
select * from t2
where :p1 = 2;
```

assuming the structure of the tables is the same.

Comment: Yes, the structure of the tables is the same. Thanks :)